# Obfuscate string in maven and then decode in java

Tags: java, maven

I have a java application which is launched from a shell script: run.sh. The shell script is part of the built java application and it often becomes out of date, or is the wrong version.

So, I write the supported build into the shell script at build time:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <file>${basedir}/run.sh.template</file>
        <outputFile>${basedir}/run.sh</outputFile>
        <replacements>
            <replacement>
                <token>BUILD_VERSION</token>
                <value>${VERSION}B${BUILD_NUMBER}</value>
            </replacement>
        </replacements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In the run.sh.template script this does the following:

```
export VERSION=BUILD_VERSION
```

This is written to a new file run.sh with the following update:

```
export VERSION=MYAPP1.9B199
```

The java application then checks the newly exported VERSION environment variable at run time, to see if it matches the version the application was built with. If they don't match, it issues a warning.

This all works perfectly, but I would like to obfuscate the build number and then decode it back to a real version in java, so it would look like:

```
export VERSION=FSDHJ£$%(£$"JKSDF
```

Then in java I would need to be able to decode that string back into the build number. I want to prevent people from hacking the run.sh script to make it work.

Comment: Hash it on both sides. Why the shell script? Isn't it possible to launch the Java application without it?

Comment: In the `generate` phase of the maven build you could amend a Java source file with the checksum of the script you want to deliver (could be done with the replacer plugin. Your Java application then checks if the checksum of the script is the same. That way you could even detect changes on the file. Depending why the script must be the same. I would prefer to bundle all setting inside the application jar and the shell script should only execute the Jar. This would avoid all those hassle with the script file version.

Comment: Even if obfuscated, people still can copy it from another release and paste, without being bothered by obfuscation. I think you need to make Java check the shell script, not the other way round, like @SubOptimal wrote.

Comment: The problem is you won't be able to make _any_ modifications to the shell script after releasing then.